# Scroll to marker in ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

Is there a method to scroll the view to a marker?

I just need a method to ensure that my marker is visible to the user.

I did find the method scrollViewportToShowTarget (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/dom/scroll) but I was unable to get it to work. I tried to use

```
scrollViewportToShowTarget( {
  target: marker.getRange(),
  viewportOffset: 20
} );
```

But that just gave me a
TypeError: "elementOrRange.ownerDocument is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scrollViewportToShowTarget()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_dom_scroll.html#static-function-scrollViewportToShowTarget) accepts a DOM range as a param. You passed CKE5's model range there.

You need to use [`Mapper#toViewRange( modelRange )`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_mapper-Mapper.html#function-toViewRange) to get the view range for your model range. And then [`DomConverter#viewRangeToDom( viewRange )`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_domconverter-DomConverter.html#function-viewRangeToDom) to finally get the DOM range.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning for other users that you get the mapper object is available as editor.editing.mapper

Comment: ```scrollViewportToShowTarget({ target: editor.editing.view.domConverter.viewRangeToDom(                      editor.editing.mapper.toViewRange(range) ),  viewportOffset: 0 }) ```